# Eclipse error log view missing

Tags: eclipse

I installed eclipse oxygen (4.7.0) "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers".
After installation I mentioned that "error log" view is not available any more.

I restarted eclipse multiple times and used also other workspaces.

How can I get back the error log view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution: Just install Eclipse SDK by

> Help->Install New Software...

[image]

After this is done restart eclipse and you got back the error log view.

Comment: The "Eclipse Platform SDK" does contain the error log view, but was not installed before - so a reset of the perspective would not change anything. Also in Eclipse you can customize every perspective and simply add any view you like - and it was not inside the view list.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try resetting whichever perspective you are using ? 
(Window -> Reset perspective...)

Comment: It has been a clean install so I did not tried it. But have fixed the problem now and I will answer my question by mself.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Error Log View is missing on a default installation of the Eclipse Platform Runtime. I assume this was missing from the "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" package for Eclipse Oxygen either (I didn't test myself).

For sure, I'm experiencing this problem in 2018-09 and 2018-12 if I install the Eclipse Platform Runtime Binary (the bare-minimum Eclipse runtime I know of).

I opened [bug 543120](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=543120) for this.

I don't have tested the hexadez suggested workaround, because having to install the whole Eclipse SDK just to have this view is too much for me.

Another workaround I found is to install the bundle "Mylyn Context Connector: Eclipse IDE" from the 2018-09 or 2018-12 update sites: it's a much smaller compromise.

Comment: Seems its now fixed: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=50517

Comment: @hexadez yes, after I opened bug 543120 and highlighted that a 15-year old decision should probably have been revised, they changed their mind and reopened and fixed bug 50517 for Eclipse 2019-03.

Comment: thanx a lot for reporting the issue to eclipse. And it is fantastic that they decided to fix it. Sorry for the late response